# How to update State when initialState is an object

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hooks

I am trying to update the state of my app using hooks and am having trouble figuring out how to access each of these to make it true when completed.

```
    const [stepCompleted, setStepCompleted] = useState({
        stepOne: false,
        stepTwo: false,
        stepThree: false,
        stepFour: false,
        stepFive: false,
        stepSix: false,
        stepSeven: false,
        stepEight: false,
    });
```

This hasn't worked:

```
setStepCompleted.stepOne(true)

------------------------------

setStepCompleted(stepOne = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to the updater, to get the current state and merge it with the new state:

```
setStepCompleted(state => ({...state, stepOne: true}))
```

However, if the values are largely independent, having separate states might be more useful.

See also:

- [Should I use one or many state variables?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables)